# Excluding PropertySource from scanning in SpringBoot WebMvcTest or other application context for WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, web-testing

I develop web app with Spring Boot. I have problem with unit test for web layer.
For these tests I'm using annotation `@WebMvcTest`. Problem is that my main configuration class contains `@PropertySource` with java arg, which contains path to external properties file, and when I start my unit web test, error is occured that this java arg can't be parsed(of course I can add this java arg to run configuration of my test, but my web unit tests don't need this file).

My main config class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = {"${pathto.configfile}"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

My first solution was to create separate configuration class with `"!test"` profile, and relocate `@PropertySource("..")` to it. And to my unit test add `@ActiveProfiles("test")`

My second Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"!test"})
@PropertySource(value = {"${pathto.configfile}"})
public class PropertyConfiguration {

}
```

For unit web test this solution works very good. But new problem appears in starting of my web app. In my external properties file I have 
property `spring.profiles.active`. To this property I assign or `db` or `file` value. Depending on its value, apropriate implementation of Repository is created and injected to my service layer. When value is `db`, app starts good,
but when value is `file` error is being thrown: `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

When I come back to my previous version(without second configuration file), app starts good in both cases(but not web unit tests)

So, explain please, why when value of `spring.profiles.active=db`, app starts good, but when `spring.profiles.active=file`- failed.And how I can solve my task?
I attempted to find how I can add other application context to my web unit tests, but I didn't find.
Any idea?:)

Answer (score 0):

For my database repositories I'm using Spring Data JPA, so I don't create implementation of these repositories, but I create implementations of my file 
repositories, and my implementations had `@Profile("file")`. After deleting this annotation from implementations, it leaved only on interfaces. I don't know why one config class worked, but two classes didn't. But problem is solved)